# ObjC: how to detect and remove invalid character from half emoji?

Tags: objective-c, unicode, encoding, nsstring, emoji

I got a string and part of it is a emoji symbol say `\xF0\x9F\x98\x8F`, it's counted as two characters by `NSString length`, the problem is I sometimes need to restrict the string's length by calling `substringToIndex`, and if the index happens to be the middle of the emoji, I got a half emoji which is an invalid character, when I print it it's not visible as part of a string but the `length` of the string contains that part.

Is there a way to get rid of this string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:). This will grow the input range to encompass the second surrogate of the emoji, or to encompass all trailing combining characters if there are any.

Since this isn't what you want, you should detect when the range has expanded and try again with a smaller maximum length.

Supposing you want at most ten characters in your output string:

```
NSString *input = ... string possibly containing emoji ...;
NSUInteger maxLength = 10;
maxLength = MIN(maxLength, input.length);
while (maxLength > 0) {
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, maxLength);
    range = [input rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:range];
    if (range.length > maxLength) {
        --maxLength;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
NSString *output = [input substringToIndex:maxLength];
NSLog(@"output = %@", output);
```